# No se actualizan los datos de mi base de datos con C#

Tags: c#, mysql, windows-forms

Lo que ocurre es que tengo un boton de on/off el cual tiene una simple funcion actualizar un dato de una tabla llamada server la cual tiene dos campos on_off y server_id el cual lo tengo en 1. Al darle click al boton no realiza ningun cambio en la base de datos cual seria el problema? este es el codigo:

```
private void Button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (button7.Text)
        {
            case "ON":
                server = 1;
                using (MySqlConnection mysqlserv = new MySqlConnection(conStr))
                {
                    MySqlCommand changeServ = new MySqlCommand("update sushi2home.server set on_off = 1 where server_id = 1");
                }
                button7.BackColor = Color.Red;
                button7.Text = "OFF";
                      break;
            case "OFF":
                server = 0;
                using (MySqlConnection mysqlserv = new MySqlConnection(conStr))
                {
                    MySqlCommand changeServ = new MySqlCommand("update sushi2home.server set on_off = 0 where server_id = 1");
                }
                button7.Text = "ON";
                button7.BackColor = Color.Chartreuse;
                break;
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Solo declaraste el objeto mysqlcommand, pero no la estás ejecutando, utiliza las siguientes lineas:

```
MySqlConnection mysqlserv = new MySqlConnection(conStr);
MySqlCommand changeServ = new MySqlCommand("update sushi2home.server set on_off = 1 where server_id = 1");
changeServ.Connection = mysqlserv;
mysqlserv.Open();
changeServ.ExecuteNonQuery();
changeServ.Connection.Close();
```

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlCommand.htm